How to change default filename for pdf download (overleaf)
I have recently transferred by CV to Latex, and I have titled the project "Curriculum Vitae: CV", which means that when I compile and download the pdf file, it is titled "Curriculum_Vitae__CV.pdf". Is there any way to keep the overleaf title as "Curriculum Vitae: CV" for my own records, but change the default filename of the compiled pdf to something like: "My_Name_CV.pdf" so that everytime I want to send the file to someone I don't need to edit the filename.

Probably this is implemented in JavaScript at the browser-end. In that case, it might not be possible to manipulate that using TeX source or available settings.

why not simply change the project name?
